# Bit names/indexing in the TMS99xx family

Tags: untagged

What was the reason Texas Instruments indexed bit names (of data bus, address bus, registers) in the [TMS99xx family (e.g. TMS9900, TMS9995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMS9900) from MSBit (=bit0) to LSBit (=bit15) instead of the other way round as it is (and was) common.

Comment: Programmers and hardware people think differently. I can't recall it right now, but I have definitely seen systems where 'engineer bit numbering' and 'programmer bit numbering' were both used, in different documents.

Comment: @another-dave: I think indexing starting with LSBit = bit0 is more beneficial for the hardware people (e.g. when deciding which address lines have to be used to enable a memory IC and which have to routed to the ICs address bus) **as well as** for the programmer (e.g. when deciding what register value has to be written for a particular bit pattern).

Comment: I feel like this is the way round the PowerPC documented bits as well, at least as recently as its introduction in the early ‘90s.

Comment: @Curd Not really. hardware people think in open bit streams in sequence of processing. They act usually top down, most important part first (aka MSB first), like all engineers. Adding precision is done by adding further units which get numbered in sequence of decreasing relevance - so left to right.It's rather programmers that want to assign value to the units hardware designers have created.

Comment: @Curd - Consistent little-endianism is clearly superior under all circumstances.  But I do understand that there are contrary opinions in the world.

Comment: To someone who spent a great deal of time designing and writing software for the TMS 99000 family I can assure you anything else feels weird. :-)

Comment: @another-dave - say it, brother!

Comment: @another-dave: little-endianess is inferior if a human has to read multi byte values in a hex dump (unless memory addresses are ascending from right to left).

Comment: Since I spent many years reading octal dumps, it never seemed particularly inconvenient to me.

Comment: @another-dave little-endian is of advantage in one and only one situation: When operating on an integer larger than bus size , as it reverts 'digit' sequence back to low address holding low value. This ofc only works out as long as access is synchronous. Only in this scenario the use of LE can improve performance. Without it is of no benefit. And no, having learned to read backwards is not a proof of any advantage - billions of people on this world are comfortable to read right to left scripts with right to left words embedded :))

Comment: @Raffzahn - heretic!

Comment: @another-dave Nop, there is only one real computer and it's big endian. Everything else is just a weak copy needing LE based crouches :)) (On a side note, while I feel BE is the natural way, I worked at least as much with LE to not feel any pain anymore :=))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TMS-9900 family implement much the same architecture as the TI-990 minicomputers, which first appeared in the 1970s. The convention of numbering the bits from LSB to MSB is a convention that had simply not settled by then.

Other early machines which number the bits the "other way round" include the PDP-1, which has bit 0 as the MSB and bit 17 as the LSB.

One speculative reason could be that the bit which is written furthest to the left, i.e. the MSB, could well be numbered first, because it's an American design and Americans as a culture normally read from left to right. The same could be said of the PDP-1, another American design.

But the answer to your question is basically that there is no right or wrong here, nor is there much reason to do one or the other. It might look weird to modern eyes, but it's only because a convention has  arisen since.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR: It's Neither Special TI Nor Has it Changed.

It's a different view on the same data for a different purpose. Going by bit value instead of position/offset is a PoV more common with programmers operating on fixed size integers. Them being the majority  of today's users (*1) only makes this seen more often than any of the other ways.

---

> What was the reason Texas Instruments indexed bit names (of data bus, address bus, registers) in the TMS99xx family (e.g. TMS9900, TMS9995) from MSBit (=bit0) to LSBit (=bit15)

It's the old naming of bits in a multi-bit-structure by *Position* vs. *Count* vs. *Value* with each representing a different view on that topic:

- **Bit Position** (Offset)

  Here the naming is based on the offset from the start of a multi-bit-unit, starting at zero (`0`). Quite handy to describe the position within a larger unit, especially when those units have varying sizes. A good example is the IBM /360 (*2) with instructions in 2,4 or 6 byte size. By naming them according t positon, an opcode always starts at offset zero:

  [image]

  *(Compiled from the 1967 [Student Text to IBM System/360 Architecture](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/GC20-1667-1_intro360arch.pdf))*

  Likewise a memory operation will always have it's first offset at 24 and second (for memory to memory instructions) at 40. Of course the same goes for data formats:

  [image]

  *(Compiled from various figures of [IBM System/360 Principles of Operation](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/princOps/A22-6821-0_360PrincOps.pdf))*

  While the IBM /360 did set the grounds for many things, they were not alone in using it that way, as this excerpt for the 48-bit Telefunken TR-4 of 1959 shows (*3):

  [image]

  *(Taken from the handouts of a February 1959 [lecture about the TR-4 structure](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/aeg-telefunken/tr4/TR-4_Technical_Overview_Feb59.pdf))*

  TI follows those conventions with its 990 series of mini computers (of which the 9900 is a single chip implementation (*4)):

  [image]

  *(Compiled from various figures of the October 1974 [Preliminary 990 Computer Reference Manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ti/990/990-10/0943442-9701_990prelim_Oct74.pdf))*
- **Bit Count** (Number)

  Essentially he same as before, with all the benefits, except it's counting, so the first one is also noted a `1` instead of `0` :)

  IBM did so when counting them.
- **Bit Value**

  That's something that only works if that multi-bit-unit comes in a way to detect it's lowest (last) item, so it can get a value of `2^0`, commonly expressed as `0` by dropping the base.

  A seemingly good early example would be HP's 2100 series of mini computers. Except, they didn't pull it thru all the way like IBM did, they only numbered the bit in a word right to left. But they stayed with it when numbering the bytes in a word and words in a double word ... the later being easy for a little endian machine :))

  [image]

*Oh, and then there's a real quirky combination:*

- **Bit Value Based Counting**

  That's essentially using bit value based numbering, but calling it by it's count instead of value, so 1..n from right to left.

From a programmers view the first two are about indexing a bit array (*5), while the third is about assigning values in an integer. That of course only works in a narrowed down environment where the size of that integer is known.

For the why one or the other many arguments can be made - one is, as seen the programmers view, which, and that may surprise some may or may not coincidence with the hardware he uses. A great recent (*6) example here is the PowerPC with its [fluid endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC#Endian_modes). Here the hardware bit (and byte) order within a word may or may not be the same as the one seen by a programmer. Thus one does need a way to number bits on a more abstract way.

That and the mentioned HP2100 hints at a possible reason *why* so many modern documentation documentation go for value based numbering: Evolution of modern machines and their understanding went thru a bottle neck, much like the [Indian Tiger](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1000585), namely the invention of very simple byte orientated microprocessors. Where historical machines had serial data formats, or byte sizes smaller than machine words or were using byte sized addressing but big endian for larger data items, the very simple mini and even more simple micros cut it all down to the byte as basic unit.

That byte being the CPU word of those micros and universally fixed at 8 bits (*7) was no longer a subdivision but seen as a monolithic building block for larger structures of words, which in turn are extensions of that byte. Making most history - and the reasons to count different - hidden.

> instead of the other way round as it is (and was) common.

Well, if at all, it always was (and still is) the other way around. Items are numbered left to right, either as offset or count. Or how does one number the bytes in a string? Or integers in a structure and structures in an array?

One could say it's laziness on a programmers side to switch from the generic model of indexing to a value based when taking bytes or words as base and subdividing them different from any other data item.

Or one could again see it as based on a different way. A versatile (hardware) system designer - like TI - will usually try to describe his design in abstract generic terms, so different designs can be compared with ease, while a programmer working with the units the designer gave him may prefer a less generic view.

Today many tend to work from a programmers perspective forged by high-level-languages that press data into those nice, fixed size units of value, not as generic bitstream.

---

*1 - Plus the primitive nature of some so called HLL. Never underestimate the influence dumb tools have. *'If all you have is a Hammer, then all you see is a nail'*

*2 - Yes, the very design that layed groundwork for next to everything we see as canon today - including 8 bit bytes and bit numbering :))

*3 - Note that the footnote clarifies that character (and bit) order is different on tape.

*4 - Which in turn not only set the nomenclatura for the 9900 manuals, but had it's later models based on exactly that chip.

*5 - Divided by the good old discussion about an array starting at ZERO or ONE (Hello BASIC).

*6 - I.e 1990s instead of 1950s and 60s.

*7 - This byte orientation is so canon today that may question on RC.SE show a total missing of understanding that there not only could be different byte sizes, but also that there would be machines without. Even more, everything is seen as bytes, no matter what medium or format and there being nothing else but bytes.

Comment: RE your footnote *5. The "arrays starting from 1" thing I understand begins with FORTRAN

Comment: @Lorraine Sure, but it took BASIC to make it a mess.

Comment: And in math, matrices start with row 1 and column 1. Therefore, FORTRAN.

Comment: @hstakeuchi ???

Comment: Since some companies still index the most significant bit as 1, we have a hard time and extra effort to teach junior developers. Oh, dear.

Comment: @thebusybee Why at all? The difference between counting of position and value of position is something one learns in elementary school - I would assume it's still present when one gets into university. Test yourself, what digit do you look at if I tell you look at digit 2 in 8675309?

Comment: RE footnote *7, the TI C28x CPU which is an active product has a _byte of 16 bits_. E.g. see [Byte Accesses with the C28x CPU](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/c2000_byte-accesses-with-the-c28x-cpu.html). This can cause issues porting code assuming _byte == 8 bits_. E.g. [Compiler/TMS320F28379D: Runtime issues using lvgl graphics library with C2000 compiler](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/935200/compiler-tms320f28379d-runtime-issues-using-lvgl-graphics-library-with-c2000-compiler/3458978#3458978)

Comment: @ChesterGillon that's an interesting example of retrograde definition to please a certain language - and user only familiar with that language. In today's mindset memory is only imagined as byte addressable, but the C28x CPUs is not using byte addressing but word addressing. Nonetheless it got bytes, 8 bit wide and accessible via a dedicated set of MOVB instructions. The concept of word addressing with bytes being handled as not (explicit addressable) subdivision has been mostly forgotten :))

Comment: It's OT, but anyway: 1) the juniors are not aware that alternative indexing methods exist, 2) the juniors are not warned by the company's fragmentary documentation, 3) after being notified, the juniors develop complex conversion methods instead of using simple math.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Thanks for the many examples from historically important hardware platforms where documentation used indexing from left to right showing that it was not uncommon.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I don't understand why you only call indexing from left to right "bit position (offset)". Also if bits are indexed from right to left it is the bit position that is expressed by the index. Also: if bits are indexed from right to left I wouldn't call the index "bit value"; (2**index would be the bit value); but exactly this simple relation is a reason for me to prefer it.

Comment: @Curd Mind to note the 4th variant, to odd one, naming position right to left? Also index is not going right to left - at least not in western writing. Right to left is only true for values in numbers - as those were adopted from Arabic writing. That's why right to left is about value, not position. I know, it might take some time to think past the convention one is used to - the creators of computers in the 1950s didn't have the luxury to say "that's how we are used do it", they had to think on their own.